# trigger fire when server date change

Tags: mysql

How to create trigger that fires automatically when server date will change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by 'date change'. Do you mean an event that should be triggered every midinight? Use [event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/events.html) for that.

If you mean 'whenever someone manually changes server data' - there is no reliable way to catch that in MySQL. You could have an event in event scheduler monitoring the date for changes, but I think it would be wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

Set cron job.

Example for midnight every 1st and 15th of the month.

0 0 1,15 * * /scripts/phpscript.php

Comment: he is asking for an action that will be automaticly called when server data changes , not an action that will be called every midnight eaven if his data didn't changed .